# Are there empty simplexes?

Tags: algebraic-topology

In the book *Elements of Algebraic Topology* by James R. Munkres, a simplicial complex in $\mathbb{R}^N$ is defined as follows:

> A *simplicial complex* $K$ in $\mathbb{R}^N$ is a collection of
> simplices in $\mathbb{R}^N$ such that:
>
> 1. Every face of a simplex of $K$ is in $K$.
> 2. The intersection of any two simplexes of $K$ is a face of each of them.

A face of a $n$-simplex $\sigma$ spanned by $a_0, \ldots a_n$ is defined as follows:

> Any simplex spanned by a subset of $\{ a_0, \ldots, a_n \}$ is called
> a *face* of $\sigma$.

Moreover:

> The points $a_0, \ldots, a_n$ that span $\sigma$ are called the
> vertices of $\sigma$; the number $n$ is called the *dimension* of
> $\sigma$.

According to this definition it seems to me that a face cannot be empty (what would be $n$ in that case?), which would imply that the intersection of two simplexes of a simplicial complex cannot be empty. Nevertheless, later on in this book, some examples of simplicial complexes seem to have simplexes with an empty intersection, so I am confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is in fact a delicate question. Munkres defines a simplex as the convex hull of a set of $n+1$ geometrically independent vertices $\{a_0,\dots,a_n\}$, but does not say whether he requires $n \ge 0$ or formally allows $n = -1$ in which case $n+1= 0$, i.e. $\{a_0,\dots,a_n\}= \emptyset$.

Allowing $n = -1$ , one could regard the empty set as a simplex having $0$ vertices: As its vertex set take $\emptyset$. It has $0$ elements and its points are geometrically independent (simply because there are no such points). The convex hull of $\emptyset$ is again $\emptyset$.

However, this would be a non-standard approach, usually one does not consider empty simplices. See for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_complex). In my opinion it would be better to replace 2. by

> The intersection of any two simplexes of $K$ is either empty or a face of each of them.

But allowing the empty simplex has an interesting effect: The chain groups $C_p(K)$ of $K$ are introduced in §5, and for $p=-1$ it would then have one generator (represented by the empty simplex). This produces nothing else than the *augmented chain complex* introduced in §13.

Comment: In the survey by Greg Friedman https://arxiv.org/abs/0809.4221 this definition of simplicial complex is recalled but it is added: "This definition can be extended easily to handle geometric simplicial complexes containing collections of simplices of arbitrary cardinality and n-simplices for arbitrary non-negative integer n."

Comment: @user251130 This paper also does not say anything explicitly about empty simplices.

Answer (score 2):

Some authors say yes; see [the Wikipedia article on simplices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex):

> In some conventions, the empty set is defined to be a (−1)-simplex. The definition of the simplex above still makes sense if n = −1. This convention is more common in applications to algebraic topology (such as simplicial homology) than to the study of polytopes.

The article cites the following:

> Kozlov, Dimitry, *Combinatorial Algebraic Topology*, 2008, Springer-Verlag (Series: Algorithms and Computation in Mathematics)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, the empty simplex is a $(-1)$-simplex. It's standard mathematical notation to include the empty case by having the final index less than the first index (in which case you should read it $\{a_i \mid 0 \leq i \leq n\}$, in which case this is clearly empty).

I do not think this is a mistake, but mathematical authors make minor mistakes and poor phrasings of their definitions all the time. When you see an example which does not make sense with your interpretation of a definition, that's time to *go back and try to understand the definition again with this example in mind*. The answer to your question *has to be* yes, because it's the case in examples.